# MySql: using @variable in select statment takes hundreds times longer

Tags: mysql, performance, select

I'm trying to understand a huge performance difference that I'm seeing in equivalent code. Or at least code I think is equivalent.

I have a table with about 10 million records on it. It contains a field, which is indexed defined as:
 USPatentNum      char(8)

If I set a variable withing MySql to a value, it takes over 218 seconds. The exact same query with a string literal takes under 1/4 of a second.

In the code below, the first select statement (with where USPatentNum = @pn;) takes forever, but the second, with the literal value
(where USPatentNum = '5288812';)  is nearly instant

```
mysql> select @pn := '5288812';
+------------------+
| @pn := '5288812' |
+------------------+
| 5288812          |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select patentId, USPatentNum, grantDate from patents where USPatentNum = @pn;
+----------+-------------+------------+
| patentId | USPatentNum | grantDate  |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|   306309 | 5288812     | 1994-02-22 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (3 min 38.17 sec)

mysql> select @pn;
+---------+
| @pn     |
+---------+
| 5288812 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select patentId, USPatentNum, grantDate from patents where USPatentNum = '5288812';
+----------+-------------+------------+
| patentId | USPatentNum | grantDate  |
+----------+-------------+------------+
|   306309 | 5288812     | 1994-02-22 |
+----------+-------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.21 sec)
```

Two questions:

Why is the use of the @pn so much slower?
Can I change the select statement so that the performance will be the same?

Comment: Yes, the original problem statement says that it is indexed.

Comment: don't be smart and answer half of what I asked. Now, again, data type?

Comment: also in original statement. USPatentNum char(8)

Comment: I just had this same problem. [This answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986977/mysql-query-tuning-why-is-using-a-value-from-a-variable-so-much-slower-than-us/14987040)

Answer (score 1):

Declare @pn as char(8) before setting its value.

I suspect it will be a varchar as you do it now. If so, the performance loss is because MySql can't mach the index with your variable.

Comment: what syntax do I use to do the declaration?

Comment: <pre>declare @pn as varchar(8);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare
</pre>

Comment: Sorry. MsSql mode in my brain (and the wrong datatype) Try: select @pn := CAST('5288812' AS CHAR(8))

Comment: Still no joy. (extra space to between @ and pn due to SO)
<pre>
mysql> select @ pn := CAST('5288812' AS CHAR(8));
| @ pn := CAST('5288812' AS CHAR(8)) |
+-----------------------------------+
| 5288812                           |
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> select patentId, USPatentNum, grantDate from patents where USPatentNum = @ pn limit 10;
|   306309 | 5288812     | 1994-02-22 |
1 row in set (1 min 21.90 sec)

mysql> select patentId, USPatentNum, grantDate from patents where USPatentNum = '5288812' limit 10;

|   306309 | 5288812     | 1994-02-22 |
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
</pre>

Comment: Bummer, then I don't have a clue.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter whether you use constant or @var. You get different result because the second time MySQL gets results from cache. If you execute once again your scenario but trade places queries with const and with @var you will get them same results (but with another value). First will be slowed, second will be fast.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I swapped the order, and there is no change. Something about the @var