# Why mysql query with varchar variable performs extremely slow?

Tags: mysql, variables, varchar

I have the following mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `login` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `state` enum("state_1","state_2","state_3") NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_date` (`date`),
  KEY `ix_login_date` (`login`,`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This query performs extremely slow (more than 10 minutes):

```
SELECT
  date,
  @prev_login AS p_login,
  (@prev_login := my_table.login) AS login,
  @prev_state AS from_state,
  (@prev_state := my_table.state) AS state
FROM my_table
JOIN (SELECT @prev_login := NULL) pl
JOIN (SELECT @prev_state := NULL) ps
ORDER BY login, date;
```

But after removing `(@prev_login := my_table.login) AS login` string the query finishes in less than a second:

```
SELECT
  date,
  @prev_login AS p_login,
  @prev_state AS from_state,
  (@prev_state := my_table.state) AS state
FROM my_table
JOIN (SELECT @prev_login := NULL) pl
JOIN (SELECT @prev_state := NULL) ps
ORDER BY login, date;
```

EXPLAIN outputs the same [result](http://pastebin.com/BWhWR0sH) for both cases. Why this can happen and how to speed up the first query?

**UPD.** I've found questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873965/mysql-queries-are-fast-when-run-directly-but-really-slow-when-run-as-stored-proc), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986977/mysql-query-tuning-why-is-using-a-value-from-a-variable-so-much-slower-than-us)) where such slowdown is the result of inappropriate variable collation, but I see no ways it can be applied to my case.

Comment: What is the goal/reason of having the xmpp in your query?

Comment: @the_pete, it was an error in the question. There should be `my_table`. Fixed.

Comment: Maybe you should consider indexing your 32M records table on the login column.

Comment: @StephaneM, I see no reasons for the query to use such index. Both queries use only primary key. There is no index for `state`, but the same computations for that column are fast. The only difference is the type.

Comment: The only thing that I'm unclear about is the join in the query...  what happens if you removee the join ?  Why do you need a "Join" and not "Where"?

Comment: @evenro, the [variant without `JOIN`](http://pastebin.com/CdJiAYBJ) shows the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution. The reason of slow execution is the sorting by `login` field. Selecting of `(@prev_login := my_table.login) AS login` field replaces the original `login` field, so the index can't be used for ordering. The query should be rewritten in this way:

```
SELECT
  date,
  @prev_login AS p_login,
  (@prev_login := my_table.login) AS tmp_login,
  login,
  @prev_state AS from_state,
  (@prev_state := my_table.state) AS state
FROM my_table
JOIN (SELECT @prev_login := NULL) pl
JOIN (SELECT @prev_state := NULL) ps
ORDER BY login, date;
```

P.S. I still don't understand why `EXPLAIN` doesn't show this issue.